# How to update all rows in a column without manually entering in update statement for every row in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have a table called equipment and column called equip_identifier. in equip_identifier there are rows of computer equipment data like this:

| equip_identifier |
| --- |
| COMP-1356G |
| COMP-2537G |
| COMP-6787G |
| COMP-2583G |
| COMP-8064G |
| COMP-7643G |
| COMP-9072G |

I have to replace the numbers in each row with different values I was given.
for example:

COMP-1356G needs to be changed to COMP-2200G

COMP-2537G needs to be changed to COMP-5881G

what is the most efficient way to update all of these values if I have 700+ rows to update?

Comment: is there a pattern to this number conversion? If not , the answer is to update them one by one

Comment: Create a static table, from and to and join on `From` and update to `To`

Comment: there is no pattern to the number conversion

Comment: then take nathans advice, no other optionasailable

Comment: Which dbms are you using? UPDATE FROM is a non-standard syntax.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE equipment (
    equip_identifier VARCHAR(100)
);


INSERT INTO equipment (equip_identifier)
VALUES
    ('COMP-1356G'),
    ('COMP-2537G'),
    ('COMP-6787G'),
    ('COMP-2583G'),
    ('COMP-8064G'),
    ('COMP-7643G'),
    ('COMP-9072G');




UPDATE equipment
SET equip_identifier = 
    CASE 
        WHEN equip_identifier = 'COMP-1356G' THEN 'COMP-2200G'
        WHEN equip_identifier = 'COMP-2537G' THEN 'COMP-5881G'
        -- Add more WHEN conditions for other replacements
        ELSE equip_identifier -- Keep the original value if no replacement is specified
END;
```